# Android Rest Asp.net Web Services?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services, soap

I am new on android, i want to use asp.net webservices in my android app.
but i dont know how i can use this?.

i want to do with Restful method.But when i search in google, i found all tutorials in soap.
Is soap is compulsory for asp.net or there is ant other option available that we can use rest for asp.net in android.

i have follow this tutorials.[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use JSON.

Json is the fastest data transfer mode across network, so your webservice should return data in Json format.

Once you have Json you can always render it and use it as needed.

Here is example to render data
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WCF REST web service

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

or an easier way is to create a new MVC4 web application, and update your Controller to extend  Api Controller, then create a new web method that will return a HttpResponseMessasge like so:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage MyWebMethod()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write([WRITE YOUR JSON HERE]);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```